# Divisor of a meromorphic section of a line bundle represents the first chern class

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

The following is taken from p.279 of Scorpan's *The Wild World of 4-Manifolds*.

For a meromorphic section $f$ of a holomorphic line bundle $L$ over a complex surface, the linear combination of curves $\text{Zeros} (f) - \text{Poles} (f)$ (zeros and poles
counted with multiplicities) represents exactly the Chern class $c_1 ( L)$.

The book does not conain the proof. Is there a reference for a proof of this statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reference is *Principles of Algebraic Geometry* by Griffiths and Harris, namely part $2$ of the Proposition on page $141$. To see why that statement is equivalent to the one in your post, you will need to understand the divisor-line bundle correspondence which is explained in the preceding pages. In particular, see the first paragraph on page $136$.